# PHP mailing script

Tags: php, html, email

I have made a small PHP scripts over 2 pages, and this is what they look like.

Page 1:

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<body>

<form method='post' action='handle.php'>
<p>To:<input type='text' name='To'></p>
<p>From:<input type='text' name='From' value='From:'></p>
<p>Subject:<input type='Subject' name='Subject'></p>
<p>Body:<textarea ROWS=60 COLS=40></textarea></p>
<input type='submit'>
</form>

</body>
</head>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php

$to = $_POST['To'];
$subject = $_POST['Subject'];
$body = $_POST['Body'];
$from = $_POST['From']

mail($to, $subject, $body, $from);
echo $from;

?>
```

And it gives me this error (and the 'From:' starting in the From box wasn't deleted!):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a8923462/public_html/handle.php        on line 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing your `;` at the end of your `$from` declaration.